# MySQL - add indexes, link tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables in a DB:

```
    CREATE TABLE `items_link` (
    `upc` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`upc`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Then, another table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `mws_data` (
    `ItemID` float NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Status_response` varchar(15) DEFAULT '',
    `Id` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `IdType` varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `IsMultASIN` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
    `ASIN` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
    `BrandAmazon` varchar(150) DEFAULT '',
    `Title` varchar(1000) DEFAULT '',
    `ProductGroup` varchar(150) DEFAULT '',
    `ImgURL` varchar(500) DEFAULT '',
    `PkgHeight` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `PkgWidth` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `PkgLength` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `PkgWeight` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `PackageQuantity` float DEFAULT NULL,
    `Unique_Entry_Id` datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ItemID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=116973 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Now, I try to set the field 'Id' from 'mws_data' to a foreign key that references 'upc' from 'items_link':

```
    alter table mws_data add foreign key (Id) references items_link.upc;
```

However, this error shows:

```
    Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

I've tried looking for values in 'mws_data.id' that are not in 'items_link.id', but received 0 results:

```
    select Id
    from mws_data
    where id not in (select upc from items_link);
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line:

```
alter table mws_data add foreign key (Id) references items_link.upc;
```

Try this instead:

```
alter table mws_data add constraint fk_id foreign key (Id) references items_link(upc);
```

Comment: You don't actually have to specify the primary key in the source table.  alter table mws_data add constraint ... foreign key (Id) references items_link; will work just fin.

Answer (score 1):

For your query I would suggest these indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX your_index_1 ON mws_data (Id)

CREATE INDEX your_index_2 ON items_link (upc)
```